# My C++ program exits and ends too early after input. Why does this happen?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

[Apologies if I use the incorrect programming phrases]

I have a program here to calculate and process a user's withdrawal transaction. I am using Visual Studio 2019. The program works fine with different inputs but the problem is during the second function call of withdrawProcess(), when entering a new withdrawAmount, the program exits and ends there, without moving on to the next command lines; like `while (withdrawAmount > 500)` etc.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double currentBalance = 0; //current bank balance
double withdrawAmount = 0; //withdrawal amount
double withdrawFee = 0; //withdrawal fee
char confirmation; //user's confrimation of 'y' or 'n'

void withdrawProcess() //the processes related ot the user's withdrawal
{
    withdrawAmount = 0; withdrawFee = 0; //sets the withdrawal amount and fee to 0

    cout << "\nEnter the amount you wish to withdraw* (max withdrawal amount : $500/day). *Withdrawal fees may apply : "; cin >> withdrawAmount; //inputs the user's withdrawal amount

    while (withdrawAmount > 500) //loops maximum withdrawal limit message if user's withdrawal amount is greater than 500
    {
        cout << "\nYour withdrawal amount cannot exceed the maximum withdrawl limit ($500/day). Please  enter a valid withdrawal amount : "; cin >> withdrawAmount; //inputs the user's new withdawal amount
    }
    while (withdrawAmount > currentBalance) //loops if user's withdrawal amount is greater than the user's current bank balance
    {
        cout << "\nYour withdrawal amount cannot exceed your current balance. Please enter a valid withdrawal amount : "; cin >> withdrawAmount; ////inputs the user's new withdawal amount
    }

    if (withdrawAmount > 300) //checks if the user's witdrawal amount is greater than 0
    {
        withdrawFee = ((withdrawAmount - 300) * 0.04); //the withdrawal fee is 4% of the total withdrawal amount
    }
    else if (currentBalance < (withdrawAmount + withdrawFee)) //checks if the user's current balance is less than the withdrawal amount plus the withdrawal fee
    {
        withdrawFee = 25; //withdrawal fee is set to 25
    }
}

void transaction() //the processes related the user's transaction
{

    cout << endl << "\nYou have chosen to withdraw $" << withdrawAmount << ".\n"; //displays the user's desired withdrawal amount

    (withdrawFee > 0) ? cout << "You will be charged a withdraw fee of $" << withdrawFee << ".\n" : cout << "You will not be charged a withdraw fee.\n"; //determines if the withdrawal fee is greater than 0, then displays  the appropriate message

    if (currentBalance > (withdrawAmount + withdrawFee)) //checks if the user can withdraw and pay for the fee
    {
        cout << "\nWould you like to continue? [y/n] : "; cin >> confirmation; //asks the user if they would like to continue with the withdrawal
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nYou cannot withdraw that amount, would you like to withdraw another amount? [y/n] : "; cin >> confirmation; //asks if the user would like to enter a new withdrawal amount or cancel the withdrawal
    }

    while (confirmation != 'y' && confirmation != 'n') //function loops until gives the correct confirmation input
    {
        cout << "\nWrong input. Please confrim whether you would like to continue with your withdrawal [y/n] : "; cin >> confirmation; //inputs the user's new confirmation input
    }

    switch (confirmation) //switch case to determine whether the user inputs 'y' or 'n'
    {
    case 'y':
    {
        if (currentBalance > (withdrawAmount + withdrawFee))
        {
            cout << "\nYou have withdrawn $" << withdrawAmount << ", and a the withdrawal fee of $" << withdrawFee << " is deducted from your account. Your current balance is $" << currentBalance - (withdrawAmount + withdrawFee) << ".\n"; //withdrawal is processed
        }
        else
        {
            withdrawProcess(); //calls withdrawProcess
        }
        break;
    }
    case 'n':
    {
        cout << "\nWithdrawal cancelled.\n"; //withdrawal is cancelled
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter your current bank balance : "; cin >> currentBalance; //inputs the user's current bank account balance

    withdrawProcess(); //calls the interface
    transaction(); //goes to transaction

    return 0; //ends program
}
```

so if I were to input the variables as here;
[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQRsi.png)

you can see it exits after I enter withdrawalAmount.

Any tips or corrections that I need to make?

Comment: You didn't call `transaction();` after calling `withdrawProcess();` in `transaction();` (not posting as answer because I think there should be some better ways...)

Comment: Please explain the idea of many of your loops which check something which cannot change within the loops body. E.g. `while (withdrawAmount > 500) { /* cout only */}` These loops are looped either 0 or endless times. Also these loops should not be part of the [mre] you should be making by now.

Comment: It's never too soon to stop using global variables.

Comment: @MikeCAT, That actually worked! I didn't realize that I had to call `transaction();` again. Thanks! :)

Comment: Somebody please make an answer or delete this question. I want it out of the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: The problem that you do not realise things need to be done repeatedly manifests all over your code. I recommend to brush up your understanding of loops and make sure you are comfortable with the concept.

Comment: @Yunnosch , yeah, my programming skills needs a lot of improvement, I'm currently studying CS. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @Yunnosch I can't see any _"cout only"_ `while` loops. Have you noticed the `cin` at the right side  of the `cout`?

Comment: @NotAProgrammer The same with this loop. It contains a `cin`.

Comment: You should unlearn the habit to write `cout` statements and `cin` statements in the same line. It confuses people.

Comment: @ThomasSablik , yeah, I admit that it makes the program confusing to read. I will improve on this in the future. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @ThomasSablik Oh you're right. I didn't notice the `cin` exactly for the reason you stated above (and because of the very long lines)

Comment: @ThomasSablik No I have not seen them. Thanks for making me aware. Oh dear....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transaction()` is not called after your call of `withdrawProcess()` in the function `transaction()`.

Adding call of that will improve the behavior.

```
        if (currentBalance > (withdrawAmount + withdrawFee))
        {
            cout << "\nYou have withdrawn $" << withdrawAmount << ", and a the withdrawal fee of $" << withdrawFee << " is deducted from your account. Your current balance is $" << currentBalance - (withdrawAmount + withdrawFee) << ".\n"; //withdrawal is processed
        }
        else
        {
            withdrawProcess(); //calls withdrawProcess
            transaction(); // add this
        }
```